# Azure availability test fired when disabled

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Did anyone else experience an issue with disabling Azure availability test before running CI/maintenance when the test continues sending requests and raising alerts, even though it was disabled?

We're disabling our tests with PowerShell:

```
$WebTests = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/Webtests" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Ignore
$WebTests | Where-Object { $_ } | ForEach-Object {
    $WebTest = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.ResourceId
    $WebTest.Properties.Enabled = $Enable -eq "true"
    $WebTest | Set-AzResource -Force | Out-Null
}
```

But from time to time we receive alerts 2-4 minutes after the test has been disabled.

Comment: Have you checked if the test are really disabled? and you keep receiving alerts?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There're some possible reasons:

1.Please check if the availability test are really disabled via azure portal. In your script, especially check this line of code: `$WebTest.Properties.Enabled = $Enable -eq "true"` .

2.If it only sends a few alerts after disabled, please go to the alert rule, to check the period and frequency. See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I have the same settings as on your screenshots, but still get alerts.